# Unconditional covariance of factors in GO-GARCH

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, garch

In [this pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf) in section 2.4 page 11 Alexios Ghalanos explains the theory behind the GO-GARCH model (general orthogonal GARCH). I don't understand why the unconditional covariance is $$\operatorname{E} \left[ \vec{f}_t \ \vec{f}'_t \right] = \mathbf{I}_N$$ but I do understand everything else up until that point.

Comment: I think this is part of how the factors $f_t$ are defined and may be needed for identification. So here the condition does not follow from something before but it is being introduced.

Comment: In that case all the factor must have been normalized and I find it strange to do so.

Comment: Oh, I see. I focused on the diagonality and ignored the normalization...